# Carousel Glyphicons won't display

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have no idea what's going on here, for some reason the Carousel Glyphicons won't display on the slideshow. It's prob a very simple fix that I can't figure out sadly. The code is below. I have a feeling it has to do linking to the right path. I'm not sure.

http://pastebin.com/zpJxf94S

I just realized all the Glaphicons aren't working this is what displays, a rectangle.
http://gyazo.com/dd538589d4b9600bb5e47f3a095714fd

Comment: Could be any number of things. Have you downloaded the fonts and placed them in the font directory for your site?

Comment: It's not a font, It's an icon, has nothing to do with fonts.

Comment: Bootstrap's CSS directs any Glyphicons tags in your code to your font directory.  This is how it is and has been set up since the beginning of Bootstrap.  In actuality....Glyphicons are fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download the Glyphicons from Bootstrap's home page and then place them in a font directory (folder) located in the same place that your index is located.  This is the only way Glyphicons (which are indeed fonts) will work.

Comment: Okay, So this is my setup , I'm obviously doing something wrong if It's still not showing up.http://gyazo.com/c73229e422cc4110b221efa26ca8407c

Comment: the setup looks right to me @RawadMerhi

Comment: On your style.css sheet try putting ../ before every fonts/glyphicons to see if it finds the local root better.  In other words like this:   @font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}

Comment: Thanks man It worked, I think my problem is with understanding directories mind helping me out?

Comment: No worries.  Feel free to approve my answer as the correct one since it worked

Comment: Oh and as far as Directories are concerned it's a Browser thing.  Locally your browser can find root files easier with ../  when you put it on the web you're actually better off putting the full address of the font files in your @font-face code.  For example:  http://justsomesite.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-etc